# How can I find a correlation coefficient between 2 datasets?

Tags: python, dataset, correlation

I am trying to find a way to get a correlation coefficient for two datasets. Such that I have dataset A, a table holding (x,y) values thats pertain to a part of the bodies movements over a set of frames. Dataset B is a different table of (x,y) values for a different body part. I want to compare the two tables of values to get the correlation coefficient,

I have tried to compare the x1,x2 as (x,y) for the correlation coefficient but this is not a valid way of finding such correlation and feel there has to be some program, application, or calculation that I can use to find this correlation coefficient.

I have 4 columns in excel, 2 x-coordinate columns and 2 y-coordinate columns

Comment: Have you tried using the `statpy` library?

Comment: Worth you looking at Numpy correlation [link](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Pearson` correlation coefficient provided by `numpy` library. The correlation coefficient ranges between -1 (perfect negative correlation) and 1 (perfect positive correlation), and 0 means no correlation. Assuming each dataset is a 2D array where rows represent (x, y) pairs and columns represent samples:

```
x_corr = np.corrcoef(A[:, 0], B[:, 0])[0, 1]  # corr coef for x
y_corr = np.corrcoef(A[:, 1], B[:, 1])[0, 1]  # corr coef for y
corr = np.corrcoef(A.flatten(), B.flatten())[0, 1]  # corr coef for both x and y
```

Comment: does this handle more then one (x,y) or will it only allow me to use one dataset of (x,y) coordinates

Comment: @CollinBergmann This assumes that A and B are 2D arrays, where each row is a different (x, y) pair and columns are different samples. `x_corr` works on `x` values of two dataset A and B. Similarly, `y_corr` finds correlation on `y` values of A and B. `corr` find overall correlation between A and B meaning that works on (x,y) pairs of A and B. It depends on your application which version be taken.

Comment: I see, I just understood it right before your response! Thank you

Comment: What am I filling A[:,0] and B[: , 0] with

Comment: @CollinBergmann You are welcome. I also added a line about the explanation of the dataset.

Comment: @CollinBergmann A[:,0] and B[:,0] take all x values from A and B, respectively. All you need to do is to define `A= np.array([[x1_A, y1_A],[x2_A, y2_A], ...])` and `B= np.array([[x1_B, y1_B],[x2_B, y2_B], ...])`